# Failed to publish TestNG Report in Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have used Maven project with Selenium & TestNG to create automated scripts which I want to execute from Jenkins. In Jenkins I have added the TestNG plugin to publish the TestNG report. But it is not getting displayed. I'm getting the below mentioned error.

**Error:**
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: */target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml*
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS

Actual path of the TestNG report file:
*E:\STUDY_MATERIAL\JAVA\WORKSPACE\SeleneniumFrameWork\target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml*

I have tried the following options but didn't work out for me.

1. Tried giving the full path of the TestNG report. Forward ans backward slash in the pattern.
2. I have tried different other options by changing the TestNG result file path but it's working for me.

Please share some inputs on how to resolve this issue.

**"testng-results.xml"** file is available in workspace. But it's failed to display the report. I have attached screenshot of Jenkins workspace and Console Output.

**Note: I am using Jenkins 2.7.0 in Windows 10.**

[Jenkins Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP0rq.jpg)

I have attached the Job configuration details of Jenkins.
[Job Configuration Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eXu9.jpg)

Comment: Can anyone please help me here to resolve this issue? I am not able to get the TestNG report displayed in Jenkins. It'll be really helpful if anyone can please share any tutorial/blog/site to check for the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few checkpoints :
1. Check if testng is producing this file at the specified location : /target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml
2. TestNG needs to be configured to generate xml report

3. If this file is there, pass path in file locator as :
   target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml
   [image: See picture]

Hopefully, you will get results on jenkins if everything mentioned above is correct.

Comment: I have already followed these steps. Result file is also getting generated in "target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml" path. But still it failed to find the result file. **ERROR** TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml 
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Have you tried using target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml . Note there is no slash in the beginning

Comment: Yes, I tried the same - "target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml" but still it's not working. Please suggest if there is anything else to be checked. Whatever pattern I use, it's not picking up the TestNG result.

Comment: Just for debugging purpose and to eliminate forward/backward slash thing, can you please try to have this file in workspace only. so that we can pass it as testng-results.xml . that will ensure it is not slash issue

Comment: I didn't get your point. Did you mean to keep the "testng-result.xml" file manually inside the project folder(e.g. SeleneniumFrameWork in my case)? I tried updating the POM file as below to generate the testng-result.xml file generated trough code inside the project folder[SeleneniumFrameWork ] but it's not created. **POM File** <configuration>
            <systemProperties>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>

Comment: For now lets keep a dummy file manually to isolate this problem of not getting the file in workspace

Comment: I have already tried keeping the "testng-result.xml" file manually in workspace. Inside Jenkin's job workspace the result xml file is available.  but still it's not working. Could you please share some screenshot or something more details on this? I am struggling a lot to resolve this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Jenkins plugin looks for testng-results.xml . Is it a typo in your comment when u say testng-result.xml

Comment: I created a dummy project, kept a dummy testng-results.xml file in workspace. Passed path as testng-results.xml and it went well. Console Output TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: testng-results.xml
testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
Saving reports...
Found matching files but did not find any TestNG results.
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of workspace. The result file is there but still Jenkins failed to find it. It will be really helpful if you please share some more details about how you have configured Jenkins to achieve it.

Comment: Can I access this jenkins instance to see the configurations or lets start chat to discuss it, i think we are quite close and it is some silly mistake somewhere

Comment: Attached the screenshot of Jenkins job configuration details.                         **Note:** (i) I have created Maven project with TestNG.  Can there be any problem with my POM file configuration? (ii) I am using Jenkins version: 2.7.1 in Windows 10 O.S. Please let me know how can I share more details if required.